# Why is there `No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.` and how to solve?

Tags: make, cmake

I just installed `cmake` but I'm getting compiler not found error.

In trying to build https://gitlab.com/interception/linux/tools on a new Kubuntu installation, running `cmake ..` from the `tools/build` directory returns the error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
  No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
  to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.
```

What's wrong? I assumed `cmake` would be equipped with its compiler, but maybe it needs to be configured before it can be used???

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The "compiler" is a separate package that needs to be installed.  One called `g++` can be installed on it's own and is also included within a bundle of packages called "build-essential".

Thus `sudo apt-get install build-essential` solves the problem (and `sudo apt-get install g++` should also work), allowing `cmake ..` to work with no configuration necessary.

Comment: Apparently `cmake` is useful outside the context of *compiling*.  See [is it possible to use cmake without any compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46176955/is-it-possible-to-use-cmake-without-any-compiler).

Comment: I already had `build-essentials` and `g++` but still encountered this error. Seems in my case I had to install `clang`. (`sudo apt-get install clang`)

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue with Alpine. After installing the following libraries, everything went through as expected:

```
apk add git cmake make clang build-base llvm-static llvm-dev clang-static clang-dev
```

Answer (score 2):

For CenOS variant distros it was missing `nasm`. Installing it solves the issue:

```
yum install -y nasm
```

Answer (score 0):

First download eCAL archives(latest version) install. Go to terminal type:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ecal
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt install cmake g++ libprotobuf-dev protobuf-compiler
sudo apt-get update
```